# shrink the size of tmpfs folders

Tags: xubuntu, disk-usage, disk-management

After checking my disk space in Xubuntu, I noticed I have files holding unnecessary disk space and not coming close to using it.  Is there a way to limit the space it is holding?

I have marked the entries with `**`.  As you can see, they are allocated 7.8 and 3.2 GBs but not coming close to using any of it.  Can I shrink them down to 2GB each?

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              205G   15G  180G   8% /
udev                   7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev**
tmpfs                  7.8G   20K  7.8G   1% /tmp**
tmpfs                  3.2G  836K  3.2G   1% /run**
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   7.8G   88K  7.8G   1% /run/shm**
tmpfs                  7.8G  664K  7.8G   1% /var/log**
/home/dustin/.Private  205G   15G  180G   8% /home/dustin
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of these directories are stored in memory (RAM+swap). They only occupy the size necessary to store the data. The “Size” column is the maximum size of the filesystem.

While you could reduce the maximum size by editing several startup scripts, this would make no difference to the amount of disk space or RAM they use.